# How can I fund my Stellar wallet on the Test Network

Tags: testnet, lumens

I tried the Friendbot. It constantly returns an error opcode though.

```
{
  "type": "https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/transaction_failed",
  "title": "Transaction Failed",
  "status": 400,
  "detail": "The transaction failed when submitted to the stellar network. The `extras.result_codes` field on this response contains further details.  Descriptions of each code can be found at: https://www.stellar.org/developers/learn/concepts/list-of-operations.html",
  "extras": {
    "envelope_xdr": "AAAAABB90WssODNIgi6BHveqzxTRmIpvAFRyVNM+Hm2GVuCcAAAAZAAAALsAAFI5AAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAluD7gjuN+bQ6cXilY5j93mN8SWMtUJV3wIX7rrxo1PcAAAAXSHboAAAAAAAAAAABhlbgnAAAAEBe2jOzd0hxRDgmbxLygvCazKukvjQadvMW9j8fvffDKietkFw27j4u7V6qWifNuV/vBCgWAF0pHMkYr9sr0nAA",
    "result_codes": {
      "transaction": "tx_failed",
      "operations": [
        "op_underfunded"
      ]
    },
    "result_xdr": "AAAAAAAAAGT/////AAAAAQAAAAAAAAAA/////gAAAAA="
  }
}
```

It says `op_underfunded`. 
Is there some alternative to the Friendbot ?

Answer (score 2):

It happens occasionally that the friendbot account is depleted. Mentioning it in one of the official channels (keybase is a good one) will usually get it refilled quick smart. It probably should be automatic on the test network.

FYI, this is the [current friendbot account status](https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GAIH3ULLFQ4DGSECF2AR555KZ4KNDGEKN4AFI4SU2M7B43MGK3QJZNSR). It has been refilled at this time of writing and can fund another ~99,300 accounts.